# UIButton - Checkmark not showing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I'm trying to create a uibutton to work as a checkbox. Everything is working fine but the view: I'm setting to change the view when clicked. When it is supposed to show no checkmark it's fine, but when I need to show the checkmark, it's not working. This is what happens:

[image: image with no checkmark]
[image: image with checkmark]

And this is the code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.myButton setTitle:@"\u2610" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.myButton setTitle:@"\u2610" forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [self.myButton setTitle:@"\u2610" forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
    [self.myButton setTitle:@"\u2610" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.myButton setTitle:@"\u2611" forState:UIControlStateSelected];
}

//action sent to the button when touched up inside
- (IBAction)moneyButtonClicked:(id)sender {
    UIButton *button  = (UIButton *)sender;
    button.selected = !button.selected;
}
```

What is wrong?

Regards!

Comment: Thanks for the answer guys. I figured out it was happening because the button was a System type, and not a Custom type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answers from ooops and Ashish Kakkad, but the problem with my code was: in the interface builder, my button was set as a System button and not as a Custom.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I think you forgot to add action event from your storyboard or by code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self addMenuButton];

    [self.myButton setTitle:@"\u2610" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.myButton setTitle:@"\u2611" forState:UIControlStateSelected];

    [self.myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(moneyButtonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}

- (IBAction)moneyButtonClicked:(UIButton *)sender {

    NSLog(@"%d",sender.selected);

    sender.selected = !sender.selected;
}
```

Button type must be Custom else you will found the tint color of button with the selection.

[image]

Outputs :

Deselected :

[image]

Selected :

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I just create a new project and add the following code. It works like the gif shows. You can do a compare.

[image]

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.checkButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [self.checkButton addTarget:self action:@selector(moneyButtonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    self.checkButton.frame = CGRectMake(50, 50, 50, 50);
    self.checkButton.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
    self.checkButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
    [self.checkButton setTitle:@"\u2610" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.checkButton setTitle:@"\u2611" forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    [self.view addSubview:self.checkButton];
}

- (IBAction)moneyButtonClicked:(id)sender {
    UIButton *button  = (UIButton *)sender;
    button.selected = !button.selected;
}
```